# Accessing an element of a custom type list by property value

Tags: vb.net

Let's say I have a class called `ControlInfo`, which has the following properties:

```
    Public Property Control As Control
    Public Property ControlState As Int32
```

Now I want to create a method for accessing a specific instance of `ControlInfo` from a List, so I do this:

```
    Public Function GetInstance(control As Control) As ControlInfo
        For Each c As ControlInfo In list
            If c.Control.Name = control.Name Then
                Return c
            End If
        Next

        Return Nothing

    End Function
```

Is there a better way to access specific instance from a list of a custom class based on its property value? Is the loop approach bad for performance?

*Sidenote*: I have also considered the implementation of a Dictionary other than a List (so I would access an instance via a key, which can be a lot better than looping through all the values), but I feel that if I resort to that I would be avoiding a problem instead of solving it. Maybe I am being paranoid but I would like to know other valid approaches here, and be more certain of what should/shouldn't be done.

Thanks.

Comment: A Dictionary would allow you to fetch one by name.  Control names are unique for the form so little chance of collision.  Some linq would work when you wanted to fetch any/all of those with a specific state.

Comment: @Plutonix Would you agree if I said that, whenever I need to intensively query for a specific instance within a list, if the property I want to query has exclusively unique values like with `Control`, using a `Dictionary` instead would **always** be the best approach?